# How to conect Zeppelin image with cassandra on host server

Tags: docker, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-zeppelin, spark-cassandra-connector

Docker is something new to me and I don't even have average skills in it, but I'm tring to create specific Zeppelin image with some installed libraries.

Ther is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
ENV SPARK_VERSION=2.4.6

USER root

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install sudo

ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark

RUN installing some libraries...
```

And my question is how to connect my image with cassandra which is on localhost, because now it's doesn't work. My notebook on Jupyter Notebook works correctly.

Definition of the environment:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.3,commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10,com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:3.0.2 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=localhost pyspark-shell'
```

Answer (score 1):

1st, the Spark distribution should be already included included into the Zeppelin image, so you may not need to install pyspark (or you need to use separate image with Spark).

To configure Zeppelin to connect Spark to Cassandra you need to do following:

- on the running Zeppelin go to interpreters menu, select Spark interpreter and press Edit
- add maven coordinates for SCC into the `spark.jars.packages` configuration parameter (or add it if it's not in the list.  Also add the same coordinates into the dependencies list at the end of the Edit dialog.  For Spark 3.0 you need to use SCC 3.0.0 as well (currently beta)
- add `spark.cassandra.connection.host` property with address of your Cassandra instance.  **Don't use *localhost* as it will point to the Zeppelin itself, and not to your machine where Cassandra is running**!
- add other [SCC properties](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md) if necessary, such as user name & password, etc.
- save changes

This will generate the `conf/interpreter.json` file with all your configurations, and you can put it into the Docker image.  Another alternative is to use stock Zeppelin Docker image, and do the configuration via Zeppelin REST API.

P.S. You can find a [number of the blog posts about Zeppelin](https://alexott.blogspot.com/search/label/zeppelin) in my blog.